# Gcp ssh issue . Error :- connection refused

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a google instance which  is initally working fine. But suddenly not able to ssh that system. Cross check firewall ,ssh keys from side and that look fine.

Comment: Google Cloud Support here! To investigate the issue, there are more information needed, that are private and can not be posted here. 
If you have a Google Cloud support, please fill a support ticket.
If you do not have support, please open [a private Google issue] (issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187164) using your project ID. 
Than post the link to issue that you created as a comment here. 
With this link I can take a look into your project.

Comment: Did you try to restart your instance?

Comment: yes. Also did chat with google support, they told I have bronze pkg. and that's why they can't help me. :(

Comment: You can open a  [a private Google issue](http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187164) and post link to it here, so I can look at it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is to brief, but it's confirmed it's not firewall related as it returns "connection refused", you should use ssh -v option to print more useful details

The other thing you should try out is the SSH from GCloud console, but remember to disable Firewall temporarily as GCloud console has a dynamic IP